# I would like to have frames defaulted to hidden until a checkbutton is clicked

Tags: python, tkinter

Novel was kind enough to help me with hiding a frame until a checkbutton was checked.

it worked great, when script was run frame 3 defaulted to hidden.
My problem developed when I added another function to hide frame 4.

Now when I run sript frames are no longer defaulted to hidden.

I need to check and uncheck button to hide frame(S)

I have tried bundling all if variables under 1 def and the result is the same.

My actual command frame has 21 buttons that open 21 frames and it will work with a little help.
This is well above my level, but I am willing to learn

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have attached a shortened version of my final file.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Dental Milling Machines")
root.geometry("1000x900")

def frame3_disp():
    if cb_var1.get():
        frame3.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
else:
    frame3.grid_forget()

def frame4_disp():
    if cb_var2.get():
        frame4.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
else:
    frame4.grid_forget()

cb_var1 = tk.IntVar()
cb_var2 = tk.IntVar()


frame1 = Frame(root, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="blue")
frame2 = Frame(frame1, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")
frame3 = Frame(frame1, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")
frame4 = Frame(frame1, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")


label = Label(frame2, text="COMMAND FRAME", fg="red")
label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, pady= 1, sticky= "W")
label = Label(frame3, text="FRAME 3", fg="red")
label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, pady= 1, sticky= "W")
label = Label(frame4, text="FRAME 4", fg="red")
label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, pady= 1, sticky= "W")

frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
frame2.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
frame3.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
frame4.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")

c1 = Checkbutton(frame2, text = "Unhide frame3 when checked  HIDE when unchecked ", variable=cb_var1, command=frame3_disp) 
c1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")
c2 = Checkbutton(frame2, text = "Unhide frame4 when checked  HIDE when unchecked ", variable=cb_var2, command=frame4_disp)
c2.grid(row=2, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not call `grid(...)` on `frame3` and `frame4` after creating them if you want them hidden initially:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Dental Milling Machines")
root.geometry("1000x900")

def frame3_disp():
    if cb_var1.get():
        frame3.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=2, sticky="NW")
    else:
        frame3.grid_forget()

def frame4_disp():
    if cb_var2.get():
        frame4.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=2, sticky="NW")
    else:
        frame4.grid_forget()

cb_var1 = tk.IntVar()
cb_var2 = tk.IntVar()


frame1 = tk.Frame(root, height=150, width=150, relief=tk.RAISED, bd=8, bg="blue")
frame2 = tk.Frame(frame1, height=150, width=150, relief=tk.RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")
frame3 = tk.Frame(frame1, height=150, width=150, relief=tk.RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")
frame4 = tk.Frame(frame1, height=150, width=150, relief=tk.RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")


label = tk.Label(frame2, text="COMMAND FRAME", fg="red")
label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, pady= 1, sticky= "W")
label = tk.Label(frame3, text="FRAME 3", fg="red")
label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, pady= 1, sticky= "W")
label = tk.Label(frame4, text="FRAME 4", fg="red")
label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, pady= 1, sticky= "W")

frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
frame2.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
#frame3.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
#frame4.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")

c1 = tk.Checkbutton(frame2, text = "Unhide frame3 when checked  HIDE when unchecked ", variable=cb_var1, command=frame3_disp) 
c1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")
c2 = tk.Checkbutton(frame2, text = "Unhide frame4 when checked  HIDE when unchecked ", variable=cb_var2, command=frame4_disp)
c2.grid(row=2, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")

root.mainloop()
```